Usage of てくる here?
キスマークなんてつけてくるもんだから　あの頃と変わってないと思って心配してしたし
The character saw his friends with some kiss marks on the neck at work and wondered if said friend fell for a bad person like in the  past, however the friend reassures him that it's not the case and the relationship is steady.
What nuance does てくる here add exactly?  it should be the "come toward me" nuance at least.

If this conversation took place at their office, it's just "and then come (to the office)" or "come (to the office) after wearing a kiss mark".
